# How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, html-input

I am working on a search with JavaScript. I would use a form, but it messes up something else on my page. I have this input text field:

```html
<input name="searchTxt" type="text" maxlength="512" id="searchTxt" class="searchField"/>
```

And this is my JavaScript code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  function searchURL(){
    window.location = "http://www.myurl.com/search/" + (input text value);
  }
</script>
```

How do I get the value from the text field into JavaScript?

Answer (score 2386, accepted):

There are various methods to get an input textbox value directly (without wrapping the input element inside a form element):

### Method 1

`document.getElementById('textbox_id').value` to get the value of
desired box

#### For example

`document.getElementById("searchTxt").value;`

**Note:** Method 2,3,4 and 6 returns a collection of elements, so use [whole_number] to get the desired occurrence. For the first element, use `[0]`,
for the second one use `[1]`, and so on...

### Method 2

Use
`document.getElementsByClassName('class_name')[whole_number].value` which returns a Live HTMLCollection

#### For example

`document.getElementsByClassName("searchField")[0].value;` if this is the first textbox in your page.

### Method 3

Use `document.getElementsByTagName('tag_name')[whole_number].value` which also returns a live HTMLCollection

#### For example

`document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;`, if this is the first textbox in your page.

### Method 4

`document.getElementsByName('name')[whole_number].value` which also >returns a live NodeList

#### For example

`document.getElementsByName("searchTxt")[0].value;` if this is the first textbox with name 'searchtext' in your page.

### Method 5

Use the powerful `document.querySelector('selector').value` which uses a CSS selector to select the element

#### For example

- `document.querySelector('#searchTxt').value;` selected by id
- `document.querySelector('.searchField').value;` selected by class
- `document.querySelector('input').value;` selected by tagname
- `document.querySelector('[name="searchTxt"]').value;` selected by name

### Method 6

`document.querySelectorAll('selector')[whole_number].value` which also uses a CSS selector to select elements, but it returns all elements with that selector as a static Nodelist.

#### For example

- `document.querySelectorAll('#searchTxt')[0].value;`  selected by id
- `document.querySelectorAll('.searchField')[0].value;` selected by class
- `document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].value;`        selected by tagname
- `document.querySelectorAll('[name="searchTxt"]')[0].value;` selected by name

Support

| Browser | Method1 | Method2 | Method3 | Method4 | Method5/6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IE6 | Y(Buggy) | N | Y | Y(Buggy) | N |
| IE7 | Y(Buggy) | N | Y | Y(Buggy) | N |
| IE8 | Y | N | Y | Y(Buggy) | Y |
| IE9 | Y | Y | Y | Y(Buggy) | Y |
| IE10 | Y | Y | Y | Y | Y |
| FF3.0 | Y | Y | Y | Y | N |
| FF3.5/FF3.6 | Y | Y | Y | Y | Y |
| FF4b1 | Y | Y | Y | Y | Y |
| GC4/GC5 | Y | Y | Y | Y | Y Y=YES,N=NO |
| Safari4/Safari5 | Y | Y | Y | Y | Y |
| Opera10.10/ |  |  |  |  |  |
| Opera10.53/ | Y | Y | Y | Y(Buggy) | Y |
| Opera10.60 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Opera 12 | Y | Y | Y | Y | Y |

Key:

**IE**=Internet Explorer

**FF**=Mozilla Firefox

**GC**=Google Chrome

**Useful links**

1. [**To see the support of these methods with all the bugs including more details click here**](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html)
2. [**Difference Between Static collections and Live collections click Here**](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/28/why-is-getelementsbytagname-faster-that-queryselectorall/)
3. [**Difference Between NodeList and HTMLCollection click Here**](http://xahlee.info/js/js_array_vs_nodelist_vs_html_collection.html)

Comment: IE8 [supports QSA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll#Browser_compatibility) as far as I can see, it just doesn't support CSS3 selectors in the selector string.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté i just checked here http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/basics.html#querySelectorAll and it told me that it doesnot

Comment: Interesting. Simple test in IE8 for Win7 shows that `querySelector` is supported http://jsfiddle.net/syNvz/show/ and QSA too http://jsfiddle.net/syNvz/2/show/

Comment: `document.getElementByID("<%=searchTxt.ClientID %>").value` is also valid and has worked for me when `document.getElementByID("searchText").value` has not.

Comment: @Amicable your App. is not HTML and JS.If i am not wrong then you are using ASP right.I don't know ASP so i can't say a lot but the methods given here are general and will work in most of the cases

Comment: Your answer is fine as is and you're correct, my app is JS/HTML with Asp.net. The variable wasn't declared in an asp.net control in my case - just thought it may be useful for anyone stumbling across this question.

Comment: But where is Method 7 (or better 0): searchTxt.value ?

Comment: @GKislin What do you mean by `searchTxt.value`, may you please create a fiddle or codepen showing the demo?

Comment: @ankitbug94
Tested in chrome and FF (work for element id): https://jsfiddle.net/p94ygswy/
And for form this works for elements name: http://www.4stud.info/web-programming/samples/dhtml-calculator.html

Comment: @GKislin Ah! I see. Nice that I didn't know about it. But after reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3434388/1533609), I am feeling reluctant to add this edit to the answer right now. Maybe someday later, I will add it with a warning to avoid it. One of all reasons for warning would be [this](https://jsfiddle.net/p94ygswy/4/). If you feel like it is really nice, then either make an edit with a warning or add another answer upon your wish :)

Comment: how would you get *all* the occurrences with `getElementsByName`? say there might be more than one index, and i need to get everything from `[0]` to `[20]`

Comment: @calyxofheld Either use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) or for loop over all of them. It is very basic thing in JS. Have you gone through JS briefly, if not? then I will recommend you to go through that first. Keep learning

Comment: if the user doesnt write anything in input form, but they click the submit button, what return will i get? because i use addeventlistener click to get the value

Comment: @057AhmadHilmanD empty string

Comment: Method 1 only gets me the original value, if the user types someting else in the input I still get the original value, how to overcome that ?

Comment: @GuidoG There is some bug in your come most likely

Answer (score 45):

```
//creates a listener for when you press a key
window.onkeyup = keyup;

//creates a global Javascript variable
var inputTextValue;

function keyup(e) {
  //setting your input text to the global Javascript Variable for every key press
  inputTextValue = e.target.value;

  //listens for you to press the ENTER key, at which point your web address will change to the one you have input in the search box
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    window.location = "http://www.myurl.com/search/" + inputTextValue;
  }
}
```

[See this functioning in codepen.](http://codepen.io/maudulus/pen/yVEOJL)

Comment: While I appreciate the completeness of the accepted answer, I found this answer to be of use re: accessing, in JS code, a value entered in a DOM text input element (text box). For detail, see my answer, elsewhere in this Question.

Answer (score 35):

I would create a variable to store the input like this:

```
var input = document.getElementById("input_id").value;
```

And then I would just use the variable to add the input value to the string.

`= "Your string" + input;`

Comment: If you want it to be a proper javascript object so that you can programmatically access each property, just do:

var input = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("input_id").value);

Answer (score 24):

You should be able to type:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("searchTxt");

function searchURL() {
     window.location = "http://www.myurl.com/search/" + input.value;
}
```

```html
<input name="searchTxt" type="text" maxlength="512" id="searchTxt" class="searchField"/>
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do this, but this one seems to work across all browsers, and it requires minimal understanding of JavaScript to make, improve, and edit.

Answer (score 18):

Also you can, call by tags names, like this: `form_name.input_name.value;`
So you will have the specific value of determined input in a specific form.

Comment: Yes! I was surprised this simplicity. Have a look at realization of simple calculator http://www.4stud.info/web-programming/samples/dhtml-calculator.html
Are ther any reference for this javascript functiality, cause I before I always use jQuery or getElementById

Answer (score 12):

## Short

You can read value by `searchTxt.value`

```html
<input name="searchTxt" type="text" maxlength="512" id="searchTxt" class="searchField"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function searchURL(){
    console.log(searchTxt.value);
    // window.location = "http://www.myurl.com/search/" + searchTxt.value;
  }
</script>





<!-- SHORT ugly test code -->
<button class="search" onclick="searchURL()">Search</button>
```

Comment: The edit is fine; commentary on downvotes doesn't belong in posts. Please refrain from rolling back when the post unlocks

Comment: @Kamil - do you know what this short form method is called for getting the data, or do you have some reference to a DOC that exsplains what this is - i've just enouctered this in some code and it had me pooring over the code base for a querySelector somewhere. - this is great as a feature, just so different to the "normal" way of JS interacting with code. Thanks

Comment: @Wally It's not great. This thing in discussed in comments of few other answers here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-properties/3434388#3434388 Why it is not great: https://jsfiddle.net/p94ygswy/4/

Answer (score 9):

If your `input` is in a `form` and you want to get the value after submit you can do like:

```html
<form onsubmit="submitLoginForm(event)">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function submitLoginForm(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log(event.target['name'].value);
        console.log(event.target['password'].value);
    }
</script>
```

Benefit of this way: Example your page have **2** `form` for input `sender` and `receiver` information.

**If** you don't use `form` for get value then

- You can set two different `id` (or `tag` or `name` ...) for each field like `sender-name` and `receiver-name`, `sender-address` and `receiver-address`, ...
- If you set the same value for two inputs, then after `getElementsByName` (or `getElementsByTagName` ...) you need to remember 0 or 1 is `sender` or `receiver`. Later, if you change the order of 2 `form` in HTML, you need to check this code again

**If** you use `form`, then you can use `name`, `address`, ...

Answer (score 8):

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="trackChange(this.value)" id="myInput">
<script>
    function trackChange(value) {
        window.open("http://www.google.com/search?output=search&q=" + value)
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use *onkeyup* when you have more than one input field. Suppose you have four or input. Then
`document.getElementById('something').value` is annoying. We need to write four lines to fetch the value of an input field.

So, you can create a function that store value in object on keyup or keydown event.

Example:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <label for="">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onkeyup=handleInput(this)>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="">Age</label>
        <input type="number" name="age" id="age" onkeyup=handleInput(this)>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" onkeyup=handleInput(this)>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="">Mobile</label>
        <input type="number" name="mobile" id="number" onkeyup=handleInput(this)>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button onclick=submitData()>Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```html
<script>
    const data = { };

    function handleInput(e){
        data[e.name] = e.value;
    }

    function submitData(){
        console.log(data.fname); // Get the first name from the object
        console.log(data); // return object
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Tested in Chrome and Firefox:

Get value by element id:

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="512" id="searchTxt" class="searchField"/>
<input type="button" value="Get Value" onclick="alert(searchTxt.value)">
```

Set value in form element:

```html
<form name="calc" id="calculator">
  <input type="text" name="input">
  <input type="button" value="Set Value" onclick="calc.input.value='Set Value'">
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tuq79821/

Also have a look at [a JavaScript calculator implementation](http://www.4stud.info/web-programming/samples/dhtml-calculator.html).

From @bugwheels94: when using this method, be aware of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434388/548473).

Answer (score 5):

```html
<input id="new" >
<button  onselect="myFunction()">it</button>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("new").value = "a";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

One can use the form.elements to get all elements in a form. If an element has id it can be found with .namedItem("id"). Example:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById("form1");
var text = myForm.elements.namedItem("searchTxt").value;
var url = "http://www.myurl.com/search/" + text;
```

Source: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_form_elements.asp)

Answer (score 3):

```js
function handleValueChange() {
    var y = document.getElementById('textbox_id').value;
    var x = document.getElementById('result');
    x.innerHTML = y;
}

function changeTextarea() {
  var a = document.getElementById('text-area').value;
  var b = document.getElementById('text-area-result');
  b.innerHTML = a;
}
```

```css
input {
  padding: 5px;
}

p {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox_id" placeholder="Enter string here..." oninput="handleValueChange()">
<p id="result"></p>

<textarea name="" id="text-area" cols="20" rows="5" oninput="changeTextarea()"></textarea>
<p id="text-area-result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple JavaScript:

```
function copytext(text) {
    var textField = document.createElement('textarea');
    textField.innerText = text;
    document.body.appendChild(textField);
    textField.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    textField.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function searchURL() {
   window.location = 'http://www.myurl.com/search/' + searchTxt.value
}
```

So basically `searchTxt.value` will return the value of the input field with `id='searchTxt'`.

Answer (score 0):

##### Short Answer

You can get the value of text input field using JavaScript with this code: `input_text_value = console.log(document.getElementById("searchTxt").value)`

##### More info

`textObject` has a property of `value` you can set and get this property.

To set you can assign a new value:
`document.getElementById("searchTxt").value = "new value"`